# iOS Google drive "Send a copy" not showing app extension

Tags: ios, ios-extensions

I have setup NSExtensionActivationRule for audio, video, pdf and so on. I am able to see my app extension in photo app, files app and safari browser. but in case of Google drive, if i choose "Send a copy" , my app extension is not shown in that for the file types mentioned above. Can I know what activation rule can make my app visible in google drive as well?

Answer (score 0):

Although it is an experience-based talk, instead of defining conditions that can be shared by plist, it is necessary to define sharing conditions in detail

The explanation is also written in Apple's official document below.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AppExtensionKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014212-SW36

You can create a custom subquery as described in the document below.

https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html

Try it with subquery.

It is troublesome to create once. You can do something. When trying with "TRUEPREDICATE", the application which is not displayed is displayed. If you use this to change to subquery's method, it should be displayed!

(It seems that this setting can not be used at the time of release, so it is necessary to change it when creating subquery)

Even when changing the search keyword to subquery, it remained in StackOverFlow.

Question about subquery

[iOS Share Extension with custom SUBQUERY for NSExtensionActivationRule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35935804/ios-share-extension-with-custom-subquery-for-nsextensionactivationrule)

Knowledge of predicate grammar is necessary to create subquery.

It is embarrassing what I made. This solved it.